# Possibility to track nearly all badges

Tags: feature-request, badges, badge-progress

We have a lot of badges that are not tracked. I think that we can track them. I don't see any obstacles in tracking most of badges.

- Question badges: [Favorite question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/33/favorite-question), [Famous question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/36/stellar-question), [Nice question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/20/nice-question), [Good question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/21/good-question), [Great question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/22/great-question), [Popular question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/26/popular-question), [Notable question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/27/notable-question), [Famous question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/28/famous-question).
- Answer badges: [Guru](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/18/guru), [Nice answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/23/nice-answer), [Good answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/24/good-answer), [Great answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/25/great-answer), [Tenacios](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/225/tenacious), [Unsung hero](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/226/unsung-hero). Also [Populist](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/62/populist) and [Reversal](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/95/reversal) can be tracked but don't care too much about them.
- [Pundit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/94/pundit) badge.
- Meta badges: [Quorum](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/900/quorum), [Convention](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/901/convention).
- Chat badges: [Talkative](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/884/talkative), [Outspoken](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/998/outspoken).
- [Yearling](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/13/yearling) badge.
- [Synonymizer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/1224/synonymizer) badge.
- [Taxonomist](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/11/taxonomist) badge.
- Sharing question badges: [Announcer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/260/announcer), [Booster](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/261/booster), [Publicist](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/262/publicist).
- Also some documentation badges (but I don't bother about them).

Answer (score 15):

> I don't see any obstacles in tracking most of badges.

Our database servers disagree.

The badges that are not trackable have mostly been selected as non-trackable because tracking them (for each and every user) would cause an overly high load on our databases and systems. A bunch of badges are very expensive to calculate and calculating progress on them is even more so.

Comment: You can implement tracking that updates this badge stats once an hour/once a day etc. This is more about details of implementation than about idea itself. You have already implemented some tracking badge mechanism, you should just share your results periodically.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov - that just ignores that there's a cost to implementing software. We have made our decisions based on these costs.